# Problem with the data mismatch when transferring the structure

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm a beginner in C and I don't understand everything yet. I'm having trouble solving warnings to the code used in a larger program. Theoretically, I could skip these problems because the code is working but in the target application I have a problem and I think the warnings indicate the source of the problem (I can't solve them).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

 typedef struct{

    uint8_t Tx[2];
    uint8_t Rx[2];

}MessageTypeDef;

MessageTypeDef Data = {
        {0x11, 0x22},
        {0x33, 0x44}
};
void Print_Frame( MessageTypeDef Msg[]);

int main (void)
{
    Print_Frame(Data.Tx);
    //Print_Frame(Data.Rx);
    return 0;
}

void Print_Frame(MessageTypeDef Msg[])
{
    char buffer[100] = {0};
    sprintf(buffer," FRAME:%02x%02x|\r\n",(Msg->Tx[0]), (Msg->Tx[1]));
    printf("TX VALUE: %s\n",buffer);

}
```

And error message:

```
E:\Embedded_C\untitled\main.c: In function 'main':
E:\Embedded_C\untitled\main.c:20:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'Print_Frame' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     Print_Frame(Data.Tx);
                 ^~~~
E:\Embedded_C\untitled\main.c:16:6: note: expected 'MessageTypeDef * {aka struct <anonymous> *}' but argument is of type 'uint8_t * {aka unsigned char *}'
 void Print_Frame( MessageTypeDef Msg[]);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Print_Frame` accepts an array of `MessageTypeDef`, and you are passing `uint8_t[]`. What are you trying to do here? `Print_Frame` should accept a pointer to `MessageTypeDef`, not an array, and you should call it using `Print_Frame(&Data)`.

Comment: Strange that this is just a warning, but with `Print_Frame(Data.Tx)` this you passing the address of the `Tx` member to `Print_Frame` which is an array of `uint8_t` , but that function expect an array off `MessageTypeDef`. You should pass the `Data` I believe like `Print_Frame(&Data)` and change `MessageTypeDef Msg[]` this to `MessageTypeDef *Msg` for clarity.

Comment: I want to pass to the function `Print_Frame` a previously prepared message frame (CAN frame) which will write me the data via UART on the console. TX is for data sent by CAN, RX is for data received by CAN. The code is only part of a larger hobby project on the STM32